# adding conditional visibility to WPF control ToolTip

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i would like to make a textblock tooltip conditionally visible.

i have the tooltip defined as:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <Grid>...</Grid>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

where would visibility property go in that definition? it doesn't seem to like any of my guesses.

there are some suggestions of just working with grid visibility. the problem with that approach is making the grid invisible will still show empty tooltip box.. which is why i am trying to control tooltip visibility.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this.  It won't leave an empty frame.

```
<TextBlock Text="test">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Visibility="Visible">
                Hello
            </ToolTip>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>

<TextBlock Text="test">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Visibility="Hidden">
                Hello
            </ToolTip>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 5):

The TextBlock with its ToolTip:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextBoxText}">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding Path=ToolTipText, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}"> 
            <Grid><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ToolTipText}" /></Grid>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

The object to are binding to the TextBlock:

```
public class TextBoxBindingObject
{
   public string TextBoxText{ get; set; }
   public string ToolTipText{ get; set; }
}
```

The converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(Visibility))]
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is string)
        {
            var stringValue = value as string;

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The OP's ToolTip is a Grid, so this is not relevant. The correct way to control ToolTip visibility is via ToolTipService.IsEnabled.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go;

```
   <TextBlock Text="Dummy text">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Visibility="Collapsed">
                <TextBlock Text="Text tooltip"></TextBlock>
            </ToolTip>                
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: i would like to control tooltip visibility. if i make grid invisible, it will still show empty tooltip frame.

Comment: Try it in TextBlock like "<TextBlock Visibility="Visible">"

Comment: i don't want to make the textblock invisible. just the tooltip

Comment: This isn't legal XAML ... you can't put a property on `<ToolTip>`. The correct solution is `<TextBlock Text="Dummy text" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding ShowMyToolTip}">`

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a year old, but you can accomplish this in the code-behind.

```
private void control_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{

    if (condition)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

If you wanted to set a property here, you could do that, and bind it to the visibility. Don't forget to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your window.

Something like:

```
private void control_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{

    if (condition)
    {
        showControl=true;
        e.Handled = true;   
    }
}

    public Visibility showControl
    {
      get
      {
        return _showControl;
      }
      set
      {
        _showControl = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("showControl");
      }
    }
```

and then bind it to the visibility property as

```
Visibility = "{Binding showControl}"
```

I'm typing this mainly to help anyone that comes across this from this point forward. I'm guessing you're not still stuck on this a year later, OP. =)

Comment: This is what ToolTipService.IsEnabled is for ... just bind that. No need for code-behind or any of these other shenanigans.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating custom style for Tooltip ? That way you can re-use the same functionality at several places with minimal code.

Add this to a resourcedictionary and include it where ever you want to over-ride default tooltip behavior -

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, 
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                           Converter={local:ToolTipContentConverter}}" 
                         Value="">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Followed by the converter -

```
 [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
    public class ToolTipContentConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value ?? string.Empty;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps..
Amit

Comment: The OP's ToolTip is a Grid, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the visibility on the grid :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>


...

<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsToolTipVisible, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}>
...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don'e want the tooltip to show empty frame. You should create a separate tooltip ControlTemplate with all your required grid and textblocks and assign it to the tooltip template. This could help you solve the empty frame problem.

Comment: +1 Seems better approach than doing it without the template and having redundancy.

Comment: No need for that; just bind the TextBlock's (or other control's) ToolTipService.IsEnabled property.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution than the other answers:

```
<TextBlock ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding MakeToolTipVisible}">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <Grid>...</Grid>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

where `MakeToolTipVisible` is your property.

Answer (score 0):

Example: I want to store information about the line and add to my canvas

```
Line line = new Line();
line.X1 = 100;
line.Y1 = 100;
line.X2 = 500;
line.Y2 = 100;
line.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
line.StrokeThickness = 1;
line.ToolTip = new ToolTip { Content = "This is a line",Visibility= Visibility.Collapsed };
canvas.Children.Add(line);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.